# ColdFusion/Javascript Dynamic Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am struggling making this form dynamic. I have a loop that allows the customer to choose 1 thru 5 when the user chooses it does that number of loops. I am trying to figure out where I need to add `_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>` so that when it loops it just adds a number and still works properly. The loop is working, the form is working when "1 Loop" is chosen. I am just not sure where to add `_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>` in the JavaScript to make the second loop works correctly as well so that it receives a new name and id. Everything I have tried has just been breaking the JavaScript. Suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Appearance of the loop**
http://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/gettgpmj/5/ (Not Looping the JavaScript for geolocation)

[image]

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
var componentForm2 = {
  route2: 'long_name',
  locality2: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
  postal_code2: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress2();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route').value = '';
}

function fillInAddress2() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2) {

      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[addressType + '2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2').value = val;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route2').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route2').value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    
document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="street_1">Mailing Address 1:</label>
 <input name="street_1" type="text" maxlength="120"  onfocus="geolocate()"  id="autocomplete"  size="54"  />
</div>

<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="m2street_1">Mailing Address 2:</label>
 <input name="m2street_1" type="text" maxlength="120"  size="54"  id="route"  />
</div>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="city_1">City:</label>
 <input name="city_1" type="text" maxlength="50"  size="30"  id="locality"  />
    
<div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_1">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_1"  id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12">
    </div>

        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="street_1">Zip Code:</label>
 <input name="postal_1" type="text" maxlength="12"  size="8"  id="postal_code"  />
</div>
            
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function FillBilling_1(f) {
  if(f.billingtoo_1.checked == true) {
    f.pstreet_1.value = f.street_1.value;
 f.p2street_1.value = f.m2street_1.value;
    f.pcity_1.value = f.city_1.value;
 f.pstate_1.value = f.state_1.value;
 f.ppostal_1.value = f.postal_1.value;
  }
}
        </script>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_1" onclick="FillBilling_1(this.form)" id="chbSame">
 <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>


        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="pstreet_1">Physical Address 1:</label>
 <input name="pstreet_1" type="text" maxlength="120"  onfocus="geolocate2()"  id="autocomplete2"  size="53"  />
</div> 

<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="p2street_1">Physical Address 2:</label>
 <input name="p2street_1" type="text" maxlength="120"  size="53"  id="route2"  />
</div>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="pcity_1">City:</label>
 <input name="pcity_1" type="text" maxlength="50"  size="30"  id="locality2"  />
    
<div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_1">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_1"  id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12">
    </div>

       
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="pstreet_1">Zip Code:</label>
 <input name="ppostal_1" type="text" maxlength="12"  size="8"  id="postal_code2"  />
</div>
 <br>
     <br>
         
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="street_2">Mailing Address 1:</label>
 <input name="street_2" type="text" maxlength="120"  onfocus="geolocate()"  id="autocomplete"  size="54"  />
</div>

<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="m2street_2">Mailing Address 2:</label>
 <input name="m2street_2" type="text" maxlength="120"  size="54"  id="route"  />
</div>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="city_2">City:</label>
 <input name="city_2" type="text" maxlength="50"  size="30"  id="locality"  />
    
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="state_2">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="state_2"  id="administrative_area_level_1" size="8" maxlength="12">
    </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
 <label for="street_2">Zip Code:</label>
 <input name="postal_2" type="text" maxlength="12"  size="8"  id="postal_code"  />
</div>
            
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function FillBilling_2(f) {
  if(f.billingtoo_2.checked == true) {
    f.pstreet_2.value = f.street_2.value;
 f.p2street_2.value = f.m2street_2.value;
    f.pcity_2.value = f.city_2.value;
 f.pstate_2.value = f.state_2.value;
 f.ppostal_2.value = f.postal_2.value;
  }
}
        </script>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_2" onclick="FillBilling_2(this.form)" id="chbSame">
 <em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>
</div>


        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="pstreet_2">Physical Address 1:</label>
 <input name="pstreet_2" type="text" maxlength="120"  onfocus="geolocate2()"  id="autocomplete2"  size="53"  />
</div> 

<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="p2street_2">Physical Address 2:</label>
 <input name="p2street_2" type="text" maxlength="120"  size="53"  id="route2"  />
</div>
        
<div class="clearfix">
 <label for="pcity_2">City:</label>
 <input name="pcity_2" type="text" maxlength="50"  size="30"  id="locality2"  />
    
    <div class="clearfix">
     <label for="pstate_2">State:</label>
     <input type="text" name="pstate_2"  id="administrative_area_level_12" size="8" maxlength="12">
    </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix">
 <label for="pstreet_2">Zip Code:</label>
 <input name="ppostal_2" type="text" maxlength="12"  size="8"  id="postal_code2"  />
</div>​
```

Comment: where's your loop?  where do you create / update `Add`?

Comment: My suggestion is to work with just the code that is necessary to deal with the problem at hand.  Once you have that figured out, you can incorporate the solution into your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving constant `id` to the elements which are created using loops is bad idea. In snippet below I have generated unique `id`'s for the elements `autocomplete` and `autocomplete2`(i have renamed `autocomplete2` to `auto2complete`). For initializing each autocomplete element, arrays are used.

Now for looping using ColdFusion variable in JavaScript, set `totalLoops` like:

```
<cfoutput>
    <script>
        var totalLoops = #add#;
        /*rest of the code*/
    </script>
</cfoutput>
```

Note that you cannot use jQuery id selector`#` in `<script>` if your script is nested inside `<cfoutput>`.

```js
var totalLoops=5;
    for (i = 0; i < totalLoops; i++) {          
        var myHtml = '<div class="clearfix">'
            + '   <label for="street_' + i + '">Mailing Address 1 ' + i + ':</label>'
            + '   <input type="text" id="autocomplete'+i+'" name="street_'+i+'" onFocus="geolocate()" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <label for="m2street_'+i+'">Mailing Address 2 '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="m2street_'+i+'" id="route'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <label for="city_'+i+'">City: '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="city_'+i+'" id="locality'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <label for="state_'+i+'">State: '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="state_'+i+'" id="administrative_area_level_1'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
            + '   <label for="postal_'+i+'">Zip Code: '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="postal_'+i+'" id="postal_code'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_'+i+'" id="chbSame" onclick="FillBilling_'+i+'(this.form)">'
            + '<em>Check this box if Physical Address and Mailing Address are the same.</em>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
            + '   <label for="pstreet_' + i + '">Physical Address 1 ' + i + ':</label>'
            + '   <input type="text" id="auto2complete'+i+'" name="pstreet_'+i+'" onFocus="geolocate2()" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <label for="p2street_'+i+'">Physical Address 2 '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="p2street_'+i+'" id="route2'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <label for="pcity_'+i+'">City: '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="pcity_'+i+'" id="locality2'+i+'" value="">'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
         + '   <label for="pstate_'+i+'">State: '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="pstate_'+i+'" id="administrative_area_level_12'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="clearfix">'
            + '   <label for="ppostal_'+i+'">Zip Code: '+i+':</label>'
         + '   <input type="text" name="ppostal_'+i+'" id="postal_code2'+i+'" value="">'
            + '</div>'
            + '<br />';
        $('body').append(myHtml);
    }

var placeSearch; 
var autocomplete = new Array();
var auto2complete = new Array();
var componentForm = new Array();
var componentForm2 = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < totalLoops; i++) {
    componentForm[i] = {
      route: 'long_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    componentForm2[i] = {
      route2: 'long_name',
      locality2: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_12: 'short_name',
      postal_code2: 'short_name'
    };
}

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  for (i = 0; i < totalLoops; i++) {
   (function(i){
     autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
     (document.getElementById('autocomplete'+i)), {
       types: ['geocode']
     });
     auto2complete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
     (document.getElementById('auto2complete'+i)), {
       types: ['geocode']
     });
   // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
   // populate the address fields in the form.
   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
     fillInAddress(i);
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(auto2complete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
     fillInAddress2(i);
   });
 }(i));
  }
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress(idx) {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
 
  var place = autocomplete[idx].getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm[idx]) {
    document.getElementById(component+idx).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component+idx).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[idx][addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[idx][addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType+idx).value = val;
    }
  }
  //var keys=[];for (var key in place.address_components[0]) keys.push(key);
  //alert(keys):
  document.getElementById('autocomplete'+idx).value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route'+idx).value = '';
}

function fillInAddress2(idx) {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = auto2complete[idx].getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm2[idx]) {

      document.getElementById(component+idx).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component+idx).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm2[idx][addressType+'2']) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm2[idx][addressType + '2']];
        document.getElementById(addressType + '2'+idx).value = val;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById('auto2complete'+idx).value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
  
  /*document.getElementById('route2').value = (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked ? document.getElementById('autocomplete2').value : '');*/
  document.getElementById('route2'+idx).value = '';
}
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}

function geolocate2() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete2.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
initialize();

document.querySelector('#chbSame').addEventListener('change', checkedAddr);


function checkedAddr() {
  if (document.getElementById('chbSame').checked) {
    document.getElementById('route2').value = document.getElementById('route').value;
    document.getElementById('locality2').value = document.getElementById('locality').value;
    document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_12').value = document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value;
    document.getElementById('postal_code2').value = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
    
document.getElementById('auto2complete').value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
  } else {
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```

Edit: Snippet Updated so that city, state, postal code are auto-filled.

Comment: Updated answer. Please check if that what you wanted. Also the checkbox is still not working, but i think you can handle that part

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. You can simply change `var addressType` to `var addressType = 'b'+place.address_components[i].types[0];`

Answer (score 2):

The first thing we can do is clean up your javascript. It looks like your page has a separate javascript for each row, that's not necessary.

Just like in Cold Fusion, you can't say `#form.static_and_#variable##`, you can do array notation: `#form["static_and_" & variable]#`. In javascript you can do `object["static_and_" + variable]`.

Your page only needs this script once--so place it outside of the loop. We now pass an `n` variable to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FillBilling(f,n) {
        if(f["billingtoo_" + n].checked == true) {
            f["pstreet_" + n].value = f["street_" + n].value;
            f["p2street_" + n].value = f["m2street_" + n].value;
            f["pcity_" + n].value = f["city_" + n].value;
            f["pstate_" + n].value = f["state_" + n].value;
            f["ppostal_" + n].value = f["postal_" + n].value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

As Leigh points out, you should definitely be using `getElementByID()` or even a library that handles backwards compatibility reasonably (sorry Netscape 3, you're out of luck) for you (like jQuery).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FillBilling(f,n) {
        if(f.getElementByID("billingtoo_" + n).checked == true) {
            f.getElementByID("pstreet_" + n.value = f.getElementByID("street_" + n).value;
            // ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the checkbox calls the function like this. Note how the cfoutput wraps the whole tag. There's really no harm in doing it this way and makes things so much more legible, doesn't it? Further, some wysiwyg editors / code formatters don't get along with cf tags nested in tags.

In truth, I had a really hard time reading your javascript with all the cfoutputs. The need to escape `#` as `##` is really not a huge issue at all.

```
<cfoutput><input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo_#Add#" onclick="FillBilling(this.form,'#Add#')" id="billingtoo_#add#"></cfoutput>
```

Personally, I wrap as much as I can in cfoutputs. I wouldn't just wrap the checkbox.

In your code, you seem to be naming IDs that you aren't using, but your elements share the same ID. This can cause you problems, each element in your dom technically needs its own ID (while it can usually function if you have a conflict, it can be a source of javascript woes when you're trying to reference by IDs).

You can give elements the same value as the name attribute, which I find to be rather convenient. I don't need to remember two different names for elements. So you can have:

```
<input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" />
```

Comment: RE: `<input type="checkbox"  id="chbSame" ...>` Couple things: "id" values must be unique.  Also, no need to wrap every single variable in a cfoutput. That makes code less readable IMO. Instead, wrap the whole block in a cfoutput. Lastly,  better to use proper DOM syntax ie `document.getElementById()`, unless you are supporting very old/non-standard browsers. With the proper naming convention, you could simplify the FillBilling method even further.  @DavidBrierton - Look at your javascript error console and post the error message.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like you are working on too many things at once. The answer above deals only with the FillBilling function, not the google maps functionality.  Get that working first. Then move on to google maps. I do not have time to look into it, but at least part of the problem is that DOM element "id"'s *must be unique* - and your code is not generating unique id's.

Comment: @Leigh thanks for the checkbox note, I definitely meant to cover that and forgot after I got distracted. I agree on everything else. I was just short for time. Cluttering cfoutputs all over just gets miss.

Comment: @David - Then your question is more about javascript than CF ;-) Since most of the javascript folks are not familiar with CF, you'll get a better response (from a broader audience) if you put together a [small, **stand alone** example](http://www.sscce.org/) that reproduces the issue.  If you do a "view source" and post the html, then anyone can test it independently.  (Also, http://jsfiddle.net is good for sharing runnable html/javascript snippets).

Comment: Because jsfiddle is designed for **HT**ML code, not **CF**ML ;-) HTML is the *output* of your CF code, and that is what you should post.  (Hint: Load the script in your browser and do a "view source").

Comment: @David Typically when you're using server side code, the best thing you can do is run it and render it and copy the rendered code to sites like jsfiddle.

Comment: Right, your problem is with javascript, so what people need to see is what the browser sees. It's good, usually, to provide the server-side stuff for the people that understand the language (cf people), and you've done that, but it doesn't help the javascript pros who can't read a lick of cf. I frequently see someone on cf/js questions, for instance, asking what's what the `#` all over the place, or the `##` doubled up hashes.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question right, you are trying to populate the input fields dynamically depending on the count that gets input. In order to do that, you would need to move your html populating code into its own function:

```
function populateInputs(repeatCount) {
    for (i = 1; i <= repeatCount; i++) {
        var myHtml = '<div class="clearfix">' 
        .
        .
        .
        $('body').append(myHtml);
    }
}
```

Than, call this function whenever you want to populate it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#go').on('click', function () {
        populateInputs($('#repeatCount').val());
    });
});
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gettgpmj/4/